# MongoDB $lookup field with and $addedField as foreignField

Tags: database, mongodb

I have the following problem with my mongodb pipeline. I can´t create my documents with a $lookup on the $addField stage.

So for example here are my documents:

```json
[
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"
      },
      "name": "Komponente",
      "parent": [],
  },
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"
      },
      "name": "Child Komponente",
      "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"],
  },
  {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "613221ff24d4242d69a17bbf"
    },
    "name": "Child Child Komponente",
    "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc", "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"],
  }
]
```

> These documents have an order which they are assigned by themselfes over the parent. So the last index is the first parent and so on.

So I build a pipeline in mongoDB Compass:

```json
{
  "directParent": {
    $toObjectId: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$parent", -1]
    }
  },
}´
```

> $addFields Stage

```json
{
  from: 'components',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'directParent',
  as: 'children'
}
```

> $lookup Stage

But that pipeline does not work. If I swap the fields so that the $lookup stage looks like this:

```json
{
  from: 'components',
  localField: 'directParent',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'children'
}
```

Then it works, but thats the wrong order.

I work also if I add the field in the document on my own without any pipeline, so that the documents look like:

```json
[
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"
      },
      "name": "Komponente",
      "parent": [],
  },
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"
      },
      "name": "Child Komponente",
      "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"],
      "directParent": "613221e124d4242d69a17bbc",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "613221ff24d4242d69a17bbf"
    },
    "name": "Child Child Komponente",
    "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc", "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"],
    "directParent": "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe",
  }
]
```

But why does mongo do this? Is it correct or have I the wrong version?

My setup:

HOST
localhost:27017
CLUSTER
Standalone
EDITION
MongoDB 5.0.2 Community

MongoDB is running in docker with the :latest tag so it should be up to date.

So I want this structure after the pipeline:

```json
[
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"
      },
      "name": "Komponente",
      "parent": [],
      "children": [
      {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"
      },
      "name": "Child Komponente",
      "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"],
  }
      ]
  }
]
```

but with the existing structure I only get this around (the parent goes to the child)

```json
[
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"
      },
      "name": "Komponente",
      "parent": [],
      "children": [
      {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "613221f824d4242d69a17bbe"
      },
      "name": "Cypress-UnterKomponente",
      "parent": ["613221e124d4242d69a17bbc"],
  }
      ]
  }
]
```

Thanks for your help and I hope my question is now clearer

*EDIT: Added the documents before and after the pipeline

Comment: mongodb is not wrong, the way you are doing is not correct, localField means current collection field name, and foreignField means lookup collection field. so your second try is correct. *Then it works, but thats the wrong order.* => provide expected result what is correct order?

Comment: So I edit my question, so that you can now see what I want to achieve with my pipeline

Comment: can you confirm this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-icYGmuXort)